# Python, convert 4-byte char to avoid MySQL error "Incorrect string value:"

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, python-unicode

I need to convert (in Python) a 4-byte char into some other character. This is to insert it into my utf-8 mysql database without getting an error such as: "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x94\x8E' for column 'line' at row 1"

[Warning raised by inserting 4-byte unicode to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798605/warning-raised-by-inserting-4-byte-unicode-to-mysql) shows to do it this way:

```
>>> import re
>>> highpoints = re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')
>>> example = u'Some example text with a sleepy face: \U0001f62a'
>>> highpoints.sub(u'', example)
u'Some example text with a sleepy face: '
```

However, I get the same error as the user in the comment, "...bad character range.." This is apparently because my Python is a UCS-2 (not UCS-4) build. But then I am not clear on what to do instead?

Comment: Is it still a problem if you use the [utf8mb4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) charset in MySql?

Comment: Not sure. I unfortunately don't get to change the charset of the database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a UCS-2 build, python uses 2 code units internally for each unicode character over the `\U0000ffff` code point. Regular expressions need to work with those, so you'd need to use the following regular expression to match these:

```
highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')
```

This regular expression matches any code point encoded with a UTF-16 surrogate pair (see [UTF-16 Code points U+10000 to U+10FFFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF).

To make this compatible across Python UCS-2 and UCS-4 versions, you could use a `try:`/`except` to use one or the other:

```
try:
    highpoints = re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')
except re.error:
    # UCS-2 build
    highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')
```

Demonstration on a UCS-2 python build:

```
>>> import re
>>> highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')
>>> example = u'Some example text with a sleepy face: \U0001f62a'
>>> highpoints.sub(u'', example)
u'Some example text with a sleepy face: '
```