# python remove IOS Emoji characters in a unicode str , to avoid DatabaseError: Incorrect string value

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a json `{u'nickname':u'\U0001f638\U0001f638\u5bb6\u52c7'}`.
When save  `nickname` to db , it raise:

```
DatabaseError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\xB8\\xF0\\x9F..
.' for column 'nickname' at row 1")
```

I think `\U0001f638\U0001f638` is the problem, they are some kinds of image code.But how to detect such string and remove them?

Answer (score 6):

I find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636489/python-convert-4-byte-char-to-avoid-mysql-error-incorrect-string-value).
Emoji infomation:http://punchdrunker.github.io/iOSEmoji/table_html/index.html

`\U0001f638` is IOS Emoji characters.
use `Martijn Pieters`'s code:

```
try:
    highpoints = re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')
except re.error:
    # UCS-2 build
    highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')

>>> import re
>>> highpoints = re.compile(u'[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]')
>>> example = u'\U0001f638\U0001f638\u5bb6\u52c7'
>>> highpoints.sub(u'', example)
u'\u5bb6\u52c7'
```

It works!