# What is the correct way to deal with emoji in Flask / Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encoding, flask, emoji

I'm working on an API and I'm getting crazy with emoji Flask/Python+emoji encoding :P

In the local server I have no problems, the emoji icons "take two positions" of the total string length, and the client (written in HTML+Javascript) does that in the same way. But when I deploy it to AWS EB, the emoji icons "just take one position", and the total length of a string is smaller, and I have absolutely no idea why that happens..

I have written a small code example to illustrate what is happening:

```
@api10.route('/prueba2', methods=['GET','POST'])
def prueba2():
    que = request.form.get("que", None)

    SEP = "\n"
    if request.form.get("web", None) == "ok":
        SEP = "<br />"

    out = "QUE: '%s'%s" % (que,SEP)
    out += "REP: '%s'%s%s" % (repr(que),SEP,SEP)
    out += "LENGTH: '%d'%s%s" % (len(que),SEP,SEP)
    out += "TYPE: '%s'%s%s" % (str(type(que)).replace("<", ""),SEP,SEP)
    for index,letter in enumerate(que):
        out += "%d -> %s%s" % (index,letter,SEP)

    return out, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
```

Local Response:
[image: Local Response in the Chrome Postman]

AWS EB Response:
[image: AWS EB Response in the Chrome Postman]

The Response headers are the same in both:

```
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 09 Sep 2014 11:47:03 GMT
Server →Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.6.8
```

But in AWS EB the "Connection" "Keeps-Alive" (of course the "Content-Length" is not equal)

Both implementations running on Python 2.6 (EC2 use that version and in local I have a Virtualenv whit python26)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I know now why that was happening...

## > Server side

Although both version run over Python 2.6, the AWS EB Python version was compiled with UCS4 support, and the local (Mac OS X) Python 2.6 with UCS2. [More info about UCS here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set).

**AWS EB EC2:**

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.maxunicode
1114111
```

**Local Python 2.6.8 installation:**

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.maxunicode
65535
```

At the end I decide that is better for our project to use Python 2.6 whit UCS4 support, so I have to update my Python Installation (Mac OS X 10.9.4):

### Download and Install Python 2.6.8 (same as EC2 instance):

```
$ curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.8/Python-2.6.8.tgz
$ tar xzvf Python-2.6.8.tgz
$ cd Python-2.6.8
$ ./configure --disable-framework --disable-toolbox-glue OPT="-fast -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common -fPIC" --enable-unicode=ucs4 LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

### Creating new virtualenv and install dependencies:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.6 venv_ayf_eb_26
$ . venv_ayf_eb_26/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## > Client Side

Now in the Client (Javascript) we need to update the way we loop the string because [ECMAScript 5-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) use [UCS2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-2).

So to read the "real string/symbols length" we use:

```
String.prototype.getSymbols = function() {
    var length = this.length;
    var index = -1;
    var output = [];
    var character;
    var charCode;
    while (++index < length) {
        character = this.charAt(index);
        charCode = character.charCodeAt(0);
        if (charCode >= 0xD800 && charCode <= 0xDBFF) {
            // note: this doesn’t account for lone high surrogates
            output.push(character + this.charAt(++index));
        } else {
            output.push(character);
        }
    }
    return output;
};
String.prototype.realLength = function() {
    return this.getSymbols().length;
};
```

Looping:

```
// GET original_text over REST API
text = original_text.getSymbols();
for ( var i=0; i<original_text.length; i++) { /* DO SOMETHING */ }
```

## References

1. [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) - Joel Spolsky
2. [Unipain: Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) - Ned Batchelder
3. [Universal Character Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set) - Wikipedia
4. [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) - Wikipedia
5. [ECMAScript® Language Specification (5.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1) - Ecma International
6. [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) - Mathias Bynens
7. [Python, convert 4-byte char to avoid MySQL error “Incorrect string value:”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636489/python-convert-4-byte-char-to-avoid-mysql-error-incorrect-string-value) - StackOverflow
8. [How to find out if Python is compiled with UCS-2 or UCS-4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446347/how-to-find-out-if-python-is-compiled-with-ucs-2-or-ucs-4) - StackOverflow