# Remove literal invalid unicode characters in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, decoded by UTF-8 but contains invalid unicode characters.

```
string = '칼 마르크스 ｢자본론\udb82\udc55Ⅰ, 김수행 역 비봉출판사 108쪽―이하에서는 ｢자본론\udb82\udc55의 권수와 쪽수만 표기함―역자'
```

Is there a way to **remove** any literal unicode character using regex?

I need to remove those literal unicode characters. Not to decode them into another form.

---

I am only able to remove them if I include the full literal unicode character, but I am unable to remove any literal unicode character.

```
re.sub('\udb82', '', string )
```

> '칼 마르크스 ｢자본론\udc55Ⅰ, 김수행 역 비봉출판사 108쪽―이하에서는 ｢자본론\udc55의 권수와 쪽수만 표기함―역자'

---

I know it is possible to replace the literal unicode character by using `encode` and `decode`, but I am looking for alternatives that can remove any literal unicode character directly.

```
string.encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode('utf-8')
```

> '칼 마르크스 ｢자본론??Ⅰ, 김수행 역 비봉출판사 108쪽―이하에서는 ｢자본론??의 권수와 쪽수만 표기함―역자'

Comment: The marked question does not solve my problem. I do not want to decode it into another form, I need to remove those literal unicode from the string.

Comment: Then please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode).

Comment: Something like this - https://regex101.com/r/n7nRXq/1 ?

Comment: Thanks @Jan. What you suggested is exactly what I need. Do you know how to get that to work with `re.sub`? I tried `re.sub(r'\\u\w+', '', string)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Mandy8055. Your answer doesn't work in Python 3.6. It does not replace the literal unicode.

Comment: It is working. Please see [here.](https://onlinegdb.com/SkSVrExkv) The code will work now for both python 2 and 3. Notice the shebang line at the top for python 2 compatibility.

Comment: It works when the literal unicode are properly escaped (\\u instead of \u). I found an alternative solution here that works on unescaped literal unicode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681921/python-re-sub-and-unicode

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Cheers =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might actually not fiddle around with regular expressions but go for:

```
string = '칼 마르크스 ｢자본론\udb82\udc55Ⅰ, 김수행 역 비봉출판사 108쪽―이하에서는 ｢자본론\udb82\udc55의 권수와 쪽수만 표기함―역자'

print(string.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8'))
```

Which yields

```
칼 마르크스 ｢자본론Ⅰ, 김수행 역 비봉출판사 108쪽―이하에서는 ｢자본론의 권수와 쪽수만 표기함―역자
#            ^^^ - it's gone!
```