# Can php detect 4-byte encoded utf8 chars?

Tags: php, utf8mb4

I am using a utf8 charset mysql tables in a mysql 5.1 server, which does not support utf8mb4 encoding in tables. When inserting 4-byte encoded utf8 characters like `"","","","","","唧",""`. The table will popup error or skip the following texts.

How can I programmatically detect  4-byte encoded utf8 characters in PHP and replace them?

Comment: Pretty simple: split a string by characters (many ways to do so) and check if `strlen($char) == 4`. Not sure if this is really the correct way to detect the characters MySQL can't handle though, going by code point may be more accurate.

Comment: Have you checked out the [multibyte extension](http://php.net/mbstring)? Also, be sure to always [read the comments](http://dk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php#66568).

Comment: @deceze That's an approach. I will go for that if there aren't other elegant ways.

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798605/warning-raised-by-inserting-4-byte-unicode-to-mysql); I know it's Python, but you could use a regex to check for 4-byte characters.

Comment: @cbuckley do you know is \U also valid in php?

Comment: sorry to revive such an old topic, but as far as I can tell, the characters you list aren't 4, but 3 bytes in UTF8 ;)

Comment: @codeling  they require 4-byte containers anyway. :) Thanks for your information!

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi you mean they require "utf8mb4" types in mysql, do they? I thought the "utf8" types in mysql could store up to 3 byte characters? if they can't I have to rethink my current work as well ;)

Comment: @codeling  I believe what i am listing are suitable to test in this question. and plx be noticed that x-byte unicode chars are requiring x+1 bytes in UTF8 .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following regular expression will replace 4-byte UTF-8 characters:

```
function replace4byte($string, $replacement = '') {
    return preg_replace('%(?:
          \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # planes 1-3
        | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
        | \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}      # plane 16
    )%xs', $replacement, $string);    
}

var_dump(replace4byte('d'), replace4byte('dd'));
```

This doesn't rely on the `/u` modifier, so you shouldn't need to worry about UTF-8 for PCRE being compiled in. However, if you have that support, deceze's `preg_replace_callback` is neater.

*(Regex adapted from [Ensuring valid utf-8 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523460/ensuring-valid-utf-8-in-php))*

Answer (score 18):

This should work:

```
if (max(array_map('ord', str_split($string))) >= 240)
```

The rational being that code points up to and including U+FFFF are encoded as three bytes of the form `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`. Higher code points are of the form `11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`, i.e. the highest byte has a value of 240 or higher. If there are any such bytes in the string, it's an indicator for a 4-byte sequence.

If you want to *remove* long characters, this will do:

```
preg_replace_callback('/./u', function (array $match) {
    return strlen($match[0]) >= 4 ? null : $match[0];
}, $string)
```

Though there may be a more elegant regex way to express high codepoints directly.

Comment: Thanks for detection but can you finish it with a replacement example too?

$a = "omg, I cannot insert  into my table, blahblahblah";
//target $a ==  "omg, I cannot insert MYTEXT into my table, blahblahblah";