# Detecting and replacing all smilies in a string

Tags: c#, mysql, string, character-encoding

I have a integration with facebook and have notice that thay sends for example u+1f600 that is called a grinning face. When I try to store this in the MySQL Text field I get Server does not support 4-byte encoded so a fast solution is to remove all these special chars from the string.

The question is how? I know about the u+1f600 but I suspect that there could be more of them.

Comment: I would have suggest to use regex to remove 4-byte encoding in a string. if you were using php this would be perfect for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16496730/761312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider switching to MySQL `utf8mb4` encoding... https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4