# Emoticons in python string - \xF0\x9F\x92\x96 \xF0

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, codepoint

> _mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x96 \xF0...' for column 'title' at row 1

s = "This is my string. Über! 0\x9F\x92\x96 \xF0"

How can I remove only this value -> `0\x9F\x92\x96 \xF0` from this string?(or encode this)

EDIT:

```
>>> s = "So simple  google.com"
>>> s
'So simple \xf0\x9f\x98\x81 google.com'
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'So simple \U0001f601 google.com'
>>> print s.decode('utf-8')
So simple  google.com
>>>
```

Comment: Whatever you have there is not valid UTF-8..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: What can I do with this?

Comment: Start with actually giving us a valid byte string; `\xF0\x9F\x92\x96` is a valid UTF-8 byte sequence (encoding  aka [U+1F496 SPARKLING HEART](https://codepoints.net/U+1F496)), but the value of `s` is not.

Comment: But MySQL cannot handle non-BMP codepoints unless you use the [utf8mb4 codec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) on the MySQL side.

Comment: I duped you to [Warning raised by inserting 4-byte unicode to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10798605) because that does hold the solution (how to remove the codepoints MySQL utf8mb3 doesn't support) but you do need to decode your bytestring to Unicode first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks. Is similar in postgres?

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a broken UTF-8 support like MySQL has.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47716217/8100123