# Converting emojis to Unicode and vice versa in python 3

Tags: python, unicode, formatting, emoji

I am trying to convert an emoji into its Unicode in python 3. For example I would have the emoji  and from this would like to get the corresponding unicode 'U+1F600'. Similarly I would like to convert the 'U+1F600' back to . Now I have read the documentation and tried several options but pythons behaviour confuses me here.

```
>>> x = ''
>>> y = x.encode('utf-8')
>>> y
b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'
```

The emoji is converted to a byte object.

```
>>> z = y.decode('utf-8')
>>> z
''
```

Converted the byte object back to the emoji, so far so good.

Now, taking the unicode for the emoji:

```
>>> c = '\U0001F600'
>>> d = c.encode('utf-8')
>>> d
>>> b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'
```

This prints out the byte encoding again.

```
>>> d.decode('utf-8')
>>> ''
```

This prints the emoji out again. I really can't figure out how to convert solely between the Unicode and the emoji.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

'' is already a Unicode object. UTF-8 is not Unicode, it's a byte encoding for Unicode. To get the codepoint number of a Unicode character, you can use the `ord` function. And to print it in the form you want you can format it as hex. Like this:

```
s = ''
print('U+{:X}'.format(ord(s)))
```

**output**

```
U+1F600
```

If you have Python 3.6+, you can make it even shorter (and more efficient) by using an f-string:

```
s = ''
print(f'U+{ord(s):X}')
```

BTW, if you want to create a Unicode escape sequence like `'\U0001F600'` there's the `'unicode-escape'` codec. However, it returns a `bytes` string, and you may wish to convert that back to text. You could use the 'UTF-8' codec for that, but you might as well just use the 'ASCII' codec, since it's guaranteed to only contain valid ASCII.

```
s = ''
print(s.encode('unicode-escape'))
print(s.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ASCII'))
```

**output**

```
b'\\U0001f600'
\U0001f600
```

---

I suggest you take a look at this short article by Stack Overflow co-founder Joel Spolsky [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 3):

```
sentence = "Head-Up Displays (HUD) for #automotive sector\n \nThe #UK-based #startup Envisics got €42 million #funding from l… "
print("normal sentence - ", sentence)

uc_sentence = sentence.encode('unicode-escape')
print("\n\nunicode represented sentence - ", uc_sentence)

decoded_sentence = uc_sentence.decode('unicode-escape')
print("\n\ndecoded sentence - ", decoded_sentence)
```

**output**

```
normal sentence -  Head-Up Displays (HUD) for #automotive sector
 
The #UK-based #startup Envisics got €42 million #funding from l… 


unicode represented sentence -  b'Head-Up Displays (HUD)\\U0001f4bb for #automotive\\U0001f697 sector\\n \\nThe #UK-based #startup\\U0001f680 Envisics got \\u20ac42 million #funding\\U0001f4b0 from l\\u2026 '


decoded sentence -  Head-Up Displays (HUD) for #automotive sector
 
The #UK-based #startup Envisics got €42 million #funding from l…
```