# How to contact emoji with string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, emoji

Im having trouble concatenating [these Unicode emojis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/list.htm) with strings in Python3 (to send in Pushwoosh notifications).

Im defining emojis as Unicode variables:

`stick_out_tongue =  u'U+1F61C'`

And then concatenating the string as such:

```
message = ' Message here...'
message = stick_out_tongue + message
```

But the output looks turns out like :

`'U+1F61C Message here...'`

Plz hlp.

Comment: That's just a string with 'U', '+', etc. You're probably after `'\U0001f61c'`.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked before, one way or another, but I can't find a proper duplicate right now. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716217) is related, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @lenz said, you are probably looking for "\U0001f61c." That is a specific unicode character code. When you write "u'U+1F61C'" it simply takes the text "U+1F61C" and encodes it in unicode characters. You specify a unicode character code (as apposed to unicode text) by using a "\U." See [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#:~:text=In%20Python%20source%20code%2C%20Unicode,8%20hex%20digits%2C%20not%204.) for more information.