# Python 3 - How are the emojis and unicode handled and read in Python? A test

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, emoji, python-unicode

I have some sentences with words and emojis and my goal is to convert the emojis in their description.

> Example: " Hello!" will converted in "smiling_face_with_smiling_eyes Hello!"

Actually I am not at ease with encoding/decoding and I have encountered some issues. Thanks to another post here [Converting emojis to unicode and viceversa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716217/converting-emojis-to-unicode-and-vice-versa-in-python-3) I think I may have found the solution. Still, I don't understand what it is going on and the reasons why I should do this. I will appreciate some explanations.

I will show you two tests, the first one is the one that failed. May you explain why?

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*
unicode = u"\U0001f600"
string = u"\U0001f600 Hello world"
print("SENT: "+string)
```

*OUTPUT: SENT:  Hello world*

**Test 1 (FAIL):**

```
if string.find(unicode):
   print("after: "+string.replace(unicode,"grinning_face_with_sweat"))
else:
   print("not found : "+unicode)
```

*OUTPUT: not found :*

**Test 2:**

```
if string.find(unicode.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ASCII')):
   print(string.replace(unicode,"grinning_face_with_sweat"))
else:
   print("not found : "+unicode)
```

*OUTPUT: grinning_face_with_sweat Hello world*

Comment: To check whether a string is contained in another one, in Python you do `x in y`, ie. `if unicode in string:` in your code. It's shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the text from `unicode` is at the beginning of `string`, `string.find(unicode)` returns 0. If not found, it returns -1. Your code should be:

```
if string.find(unicode) != -1:
   print("after: "+string.replace(unicode,"grinning_face_with_sweat"))
else:
   print("not found : "+unicode)
```

BTW, are you still using Python 2? I strongly suggest switching to Python 3. And if you're using Python 3, there's no need to precede strings with `u`, since all strings in Python 3 are Unicode.